# How to extracting only text from the .ppt using Apache Tika

Tags: apache-tika

public class Test {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String data;
        TikaConfig tikaConfig = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        ContentHandler handler;
        try (InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\AllTypes\\PPT\\Presentation1.pptx")))) {
            Detector detector = tikaConfig.getDetector();
            Parser parser = tikaConfig.getParser();
            MediaType type = detector.detect(stream, metadata);
            metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, type.toString());
            handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
            parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
            data = handler.toString();
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }
}
```

I have only Hello world! in the input ppt So i want only Hello world!
Output: [Content_Types].xml

_rels/.rels

ppt/slides/_rels/slide1.xml.rels

ppt/_rels/presentation.xml.rels

ppt/presentation.xml

ppt/slides/slide1.xml
                                 Hello world!

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout6.xml.rels

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout7.xml.rels

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout9.xml.rels

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout10.xml.rels

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout8.xml.rels

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout11.xml.rels

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout1.xml.rels

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout2.xml.rels

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout3.xml.rels

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout4.xml.rels

ppt/slideMasters/_rels/slideMaster1.xml.rels

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout11.xml
                               Click to edit Master title style                    Click to edit Master text styles     Second level     Third level     Fourth level     Fifth level                1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout10.xml
                            Click to edit Master title style                 Click to edit Master text styles     Second level     Third level     Fourth level     Fifth level                1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout3.xml
                                 Click to edit Master title style                                                                          Click to edit Master text styles               1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout2.xml
                            Click to edit Master title style                 Click to edit Master text styles     Second level     Third level     Fourth level     Fifth level                1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout1.xml
                                 Click to edit Master title style                                              Click to edit Master subtitle style                1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideMasters/slideMaster1.xml
                                     Click to edit Master title style                       Click to edit Master text styles     Second level     Third level     Fourth level     Fifth level                          1/30/2018                                                 ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout4.xml
                            Click to edit Master title style                    Click to edit Master text styles     Second level     Third level     Fourth level     Fifth level                    Click to edit Master text styles     Second level     Third level     Fourth level     Fifth level                1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout5.xml
                               Click to edit Master title style                                               Click to edit Master text styles                   Click to edit Master text styles     Second level     Third level     Fourth level     Fifth level                                               Click to edit Master text styles                   Click to edit Master text styles     Second level     Third level     Fourth level     Fifth level                1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout6.xml
                            Click to edit Master title style                1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout7.xml
                            1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout8.xml
                                 Click to edit Master title style                                      Click to edit Master text styles     Second level     Third level     Fourth level     Fifth level                                               Click to edit Master text styles               1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout9.xml
                                 Click to edit Master title style                                                                                          Click to edit Master text styles               1/30/2018                             ‹#›

ppt/slideLayouts/_rels/slideLayout5.xml.rels

ppt/theme/theme1.xml

docProps/thumbnail.jpeg

ppt/presProps.xml

ppt/tableStyles.xml

ppt/viewProps.xml

docProps/core.xml
  PowerPoint Presentation srinuk srinuk 1 2018-01-30T10:19:34Z 2018-01-30T10:22:05Z

docProps/app.xml
  2 3 Microsoft Office PowerPoint Widescreen 1 1 0 0 0 false    Fonts Used  3  Theme  1  Slide Titles  1   Arial Calibri Calibri Light Office Theme PowerPoint Presentation  false false false 15.0000

Comment: What happens if you use AutoDetectParser? How did you add Tika to your project? Did you perhaps forget some of the dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use tika-app.jar.Just use a Tika extract text function.

`Tika tika = new Tika();
File file = new File("path");
String str = tika.parseToString(file);`

This code just parses text content from the file.

Comment: Xiao may i use tika-app.jar in production

Comment: Of course you can.I alse use the jar package in my java program.It's quite easy to use tika.What's more,you can also choose to some parsers that you need to deal with the file.